# Parsing logs in Zabbix

Tags: parsing, logging, zabbix

i'm try to parse logs from windows folder in Zabbix, but everyday creates a new directory like "2022_03_15" and log files in her, how parse a new name directory?

`log["C:\Windows\Temp\app\web\0\Log\YYYY_MM_DD\Application.log"]`

Answer (score 1):

The logrt item would come closest but reading https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent#supported-item-keys
It notes:
file_regexp - absolute path to file and the file name described by a regular expression. Note that only the file name is a regular expression

So, sadly, this is not possible yet.

You could try to work around this by first using a list to find the latest directory and use lld to create a new log item when that is needed. For these cases it is a pity that the file and location are part of the item key.